What is the expected size of a single distribution Ubuntu Repository Mirror?
I've recently set up a homelab and now that I finally have plenty of storage I decided it might be a good idea to keep a copy of the Ubuntu packages for a single LTS release. In particular, I decided to mirror 24.04 Noble. Ideally, the goal is to be able to install packages and fresh ubuntu installs using my mirror, and only occasionally updates (most of my machines aren't connected to the external network) when I can update the mirror (maybe once a month or so). I also just thought it would be a fun learning experience.
I followed some guides to the best of my ability and did some of my own reading, and settled on using debmirror with the following script in a docker container to perform the mirroring operation:
#!/bin/bash

SECTIONS="main,restricted,universe,multiverse"
RELEASE="noble,noble-security,noble-updates,noble-backports"
PROTO="rsync"

AMD64_ARCHES="amd64"
AMD64_ROOT="ubuntu"
AMD64_SERVER="us.archive.ubuntu.com"
AMD64_DEST="/mirror/amd64/ubuntu"

ARM64_ARCHES="arm64"
ARM64_ROOT="ubuntu-ports"
ARM64_SERVER="us.ports.ubuntu.com"
ARM64_DEST="/mirror/arm64/ubuntu"

# Mirror AMD
debmirror --arch="$AMD64_ARCHES"\
          --section="$SECTIONS" \
          --host="$AMD64_SERVER"\
          --method="$PROTO"     \
          --root=$AMD64_ROOT    \
          --dist="$RELEASE"     \
          --source              \
          --progress            \
          --cleanup             \
          --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg \
          --rsync-options "-aIL --info=progress2 --partial" \
          "$AMD64_DEST"

# Mirror ARM64
debmirror --arch="$ARM64_ARCHES"\
          --section="$SECTIONS" \
          --host="$ARM64_SERVER"\
          --method="$PROTO"     \
          --root=$ARM64_ROOT    \
          --dist="$RELEASE"     \
          --source              \
          --progress            \
          --cleanup             \
          --keyring=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg \
          --rsync-options "-aIL --info=progress2 --partial" \
          "$ARM64_DEST"

I have a repo with all the code and the Dockerfile if that is important on github.
According to answers to the following question, it seems like if I mirrored the entire repo I could expect to use 2.1TB of data: size of mirror repositories
I expected this would be less for mirroring only a single distribution, but I wasn't sure how much less. The amount that I have mirrored is roughly 260GB for BOTH amd64 and arm64 when mirroring both, with both halves taking up approximately the same amount of space. That is significantly less than I was expecting, and I want to make sure I haven't missed anything. I had assumed most of the distributions would share packages where applicable, so I wasn't expecting a massive reduction in size from a single distribution.
Edit: The following question (What is the size of Ubuntu repository?) also came up, but my concern is that the most relevant answer appears to be from 12 years ago, and a lot can change between then and now. It also appears to leave out the universe section, though as I am unfamiliar with the older releases maybe that was simply a different structure at the time.

The numbers seem OK. The linked post is for all releases, not just a single one, and there are usually 5 active at any given time, plus maybe one that hasn't been moved to old releases yet, so the main archive would have ~2.1/6/2 (for both amd64 and i386) ~180GB, and 130GB for a single release and amd64 seems fine for a relatively new release that hasn't seen as much activity in the updates/proposed/etc. pockets as older releases

This question is similar to: What is the size of Ubuntu repository?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

But you can just use apt-mirror to get an accurate estimate as shown above.

@muru I did see that question, but being 12 years ago it was hard to discern if the answers were still correct/relevant, and of the two answers the one closest to answering mine left out the universe section, which seems by far the biggest at least in my current mirror.
I appreciate the comments, though. I hadn't also considered the lack of updates compared to older versions. Much appreciate the information!

The method is still relevant, the numbers will of course keep changing. There's not much point having a post every now and then just updating a constantly changing number

When I mirrored bionic and focal it was 427 G.

